# How to arrange textboxes using jquery in .net mvc4?

Tags: jquery, html, .net, jquery-plugins, asp.net-mvc-4

I have got a task to arrange the textboxes in the page. This is my html code. This code is automatically generated. I want to arrange the positon of the textboxes defaultly by creating.

```
@model Resume.Models.Resume

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Resume</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gender)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Country)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HighSchool)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HighSchool)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HighSchool)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CollegePer)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CollegePer)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CollegePer)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Qualification)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Qualification)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Qualification)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DegreeYearOfPassout)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DegreeYearOfPassout)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DegreeYearOfPassout)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PreviousCompanyName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PreviousCompanyName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PreviousCompanyName)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

How can i do this? Is there any jquery plug in or any jquery code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define CSS class

```
div.editor-field input[type=text]
{
 margin: 0 0 0 0; //just a sample position
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
 ....
}
```

then every time you drop

```
 <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CollegePer)

        </div>
```

it will be arranged automatically

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, you can get the element by id (you have to set their id), and manipulate their css attributes.

I said by id, in case you need to position them in diferent positions. If you need to move all the objects of the same class, you can get them by class (Changing the # selector for a .).

The jquery code is the following:

```
$('#ID').css({ 'ATRIBUTE NAME': 'VALUE' });
```

So, lets see an example....

If you want to change the display of an element with id=myElement, you would do...

```
$('#myElement').css({ 'display': 'none' });
```

You can find the appropiate documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) or [here](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Comment: Actually I want to create that in automatically. I know the way you told.

Comment: Automatically how? could you explain a bit more in detail? also, you should add that to the description :)

Answer (score 0):

If you Add ID to your element you can do it in CSS.  By specifing the ID

Something like :

```
#ID_ELEMENT
{
 attribute : ...;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to avoid writing javascript, each of those elements have classes so you could target them in your css easily enough. If you needed to do anything for specific ones however you'll need to add ID's to the generated markup, or use some more advanced css selector techniques, but as the code is generated to make it more robust I'd recommend ID's as you cant grantee the order of the elements.

Comment: Is it possible with scaffolding.

Answer (score 0):

If u are using this `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age)` then the id of the element on page will be #age ..

```
<style>
#age {
ur css here 
}
</style>
use this style to arrange for each once ..
```